# Where are the Gamma rays in Beryllium-7 decay coming from?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, radioactivity, gamma-rays, elements

Beryllium-7 decays via electron capture.
This gives of Neutrino and later a Auger electron/Extreme ultraviolet photon.
So where does the Gamma rays that occur 10% of time according to [here](http://www.hpschapters.org/northcarolina/NSDS/7BePDF.pdf)  come from?

Comment: From the decay going to an excited state of the daughter nucleus, which then emits the gamma. The TUNL nuclear data project has nice energy level diagrams, and your local ENSDF mirror will have lots of info (including gamma lines).

Comment: In other words:  they come from the same place they come from in any radioactive decay in which gammas are emitted.  (More or less.)  Can you elaborate on why you think Be-7 might be different in some way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

${}^7\mathrm{Be}$ decays exclusively by electron capture to form ${}^7\mathrm{Li}$, but it can decay into the first excited state of lithium, and the excited lithium nucleus then decays by emission of a $477.6$ keV gamma ray. Indeed, this gamma radiation is routinely used as a way of detecting ${}^7\mathrm{Be}$ produced by cosmic rays.

The decay scheme from the Evaluated Nuclear Structure Data File ([ENSDF](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/)) shows:

[image: Be-7 electron capture decay scheme]